# calculate bounce rate by day

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like a really easy task, but I have been struggling with it for a while.

I want to calculated the (number of sessions with PageView==1) / (total number of sessions) per day, sample data below

`session_df`

```
Date/Timestamp  Session ID  PageViews
2/14/2016          a           1
2/14/2016          b           5
2/14/2016          c           8
3/23/2016          d           1
3/23/2016          e           1
3/23/2016          f           2
```

and the expected output:

```
Date/Timestamp  BounceRate
2/14/2016       0.333333333
3/23/2016       0.666666667
```

I tried first add a `Bounced?` column based on the PageViews number, then groupby and calculate the percentage, then I need to filter out the `bounced?==False` which is very cumbersome. If anyone can suggest a better way for doing this that would be great!

```
sessions_df['Bounced?'] = sessions_df['PageViews']>1
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(sessions_df['Date/Timestamp'])
daily_session_bounce_rate = sessions_df.groupby([dt.date, 'Bounced?']).agg({'Session ID':'count'})

daily_session_bounce_rate = daily_session_bounce_rate.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
daily_session_bounce_rate
# this is my output
           Bounced? Session ID
2016-01-01  False   0.459893
            True    0.540107


#filter data
daily_session_bounce_rate.loc[daily_session_bounce_rate['Bounced?']==True,['level_0','Session ID']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
bouncerate = (df.loc[df['PageViews'] == 1]
              .groupby('Date/Timestamp')['Session ID'].count()
              .div(df.groupby('Date/Timestamp')['Session ID']
                   .count())
              .to_frame('Bounce Rate'))
```

Or:

```
bouncerate = (df.groupby('Date/Timestamp')
              .apply(lambda x: sum(x.PageViews == 1) / x.PageViews.count())
              .to_frame('Bounce Rate'))
```

Both result in:

```
>>> bouncerate
                    Bounce Rate
Date/Timestamp             
2/14/2016          0.333333
3/23/2016          0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You not need define separate `Bounced?` column. Take `count` of grouped rows where `PageViews==1` and divide by number of all rows for that date to get fraction

```
daily_session_bounce_rate = \
    df[df['PageViews']==1].groupby('Date/Timestamp').agg({'Session ID':'count'}) /\
    df.groupby('Date/Timestamp').agg({'Session ID':'count'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
grp = session_df.groupby(session_df['Date/Timestamp'].dt.day)['Session_ID'].count()
session_1 = session_df.loc[session_df['PageViews']==1].groupby(session_df['Date/Timestamp'].dt.day)['Session_ID'].count()
pd.DataFrame({'bouncerate':list(session_1/grp)}, index=session_df['Date/Timestamp'].unique())
```

Output:

```
           bouncerate
2016-02-14  0.333333
2016-03-23  0.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sessions_df['bounced?'] = sessions_df['PageViews']==1
daily_session_bounce_rate = sessions_df.groupby('Date/Timestamp').mean()['bounced?']
```

The first line creates a column based of whether `PageViews` is equal to 1. This is opposite from how you did it; you had `bounced?` be `True` when `PageViews` is more than 1 ... which, if I understand your use of "bounced" correctly, is a case where the user *didn't* bounce.

The second line groups by `Date/Timestamp` and then takes the mean. Whenever you do math with booleans like this, Python casts them as int, so every time someone bounces, that's True/1, and whenever they don't, that's False/0. Thus, the sum of the values of the booleans as int is the same as the count of True. When you tell pandas to take the mean of a Series of booleans, it takes the sum/count of True, and divides by the total number of values, which is the same as finding the percentage of times you have True.

Thus, grouping by Date and taking the mean gives you a dataframe where the rows are dates and the columns are the means for that date. The resulting dataframe has a column for each column of the original dataframe (in this case, you have a column consisting of the mean `PageViews` for each date, and a column of the mean `bounced?` for each date). If you just want the bounce percentage, you can subset the data frame with `['bounced?']`

Comment: It is helpful to describe what is going on with your code. This will give context and help the OP as well as people that come across this answer in the future.